# How to enable Directory browsing by default on IIS Express

Tags: iis, iis-express, cassini, directory-browsing

Cassini (Visual Studio development web server) by default enables directory browsing, how can I enable directory browsing on IIS Express by default? (I don't want to have a separate configuration for each project I have?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use AppCmd.exe to manage IIS Express.  Try this:

```
appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

More info on AppCmd.exe here:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

Comment: Be an admin
run this
      %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true

Comment: I had to run the copy of appcmd that lived in `%programFiles(x86)%\IIS Express\` . If I ran the other copy, the setting would not take. I guess I have 2 versions of IIS installed. http://forums.iis.net/post/1993018.aspx

Comment: @WalterStabosz Thanks for that comment. I got this to work, by following your comment.

Comment: `ERROR ( hresult:80070020, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Answer (score 31):

1. Go to `Web.config` file of your project.
2. Add the below two tags in `<system.webServer>` tag in `web.config`

`<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />`

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Comment: This one worked for me for Visual Studio 2017 (info! do not forget to create <system.webServer> tags in web.config, because they are not there)

Comment: Thanks!! This saved my day. Worked for me Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @Moni: Can you advise little more on your answer? After adding advised elements in web.config my web api application listed directory structure. Should not it had run with a default controller at first place?

Answer (score 6):

you can use `appcmd` tool

```
APPCMD (command) (object-type) <identifier> < /parameter1:value1 ... >*
```

Where  is one of the commands supported by .Most objects support this basic set of commands:

**LIST** Display the objects on the machine. An optional  can specify a unique object to list, or one or more parameters can be specified to match against object properties.

**ADD** Create a new object with the specified object properties to set during creation.

**DELETE** Delete the object specified by the .

**SET** Set parameters on the object specified by .

Enable directory browsing.

Go to the `IIS` Express install directory.

1: **Enable directory browsing at the server level**

```
Run `appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true`
```

2: **Enable directory browsing at the site level**

```
Run `appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true`
```

**Note**: Run with elevated permission

*you can  verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.*

Reference : [IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe)

Answer (score 2):

for those coming across this years later: directory browsing can also be enabled via IIS Manager:

[image: IIS Manager Directory Browsing]

Comment: Thanks.  That's precisely what I needed for a project folder on my localhost.