# HTTP Error 403.14 - The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. in .NET core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have project which don't have .sln file as well. I am trying to run but facing error.

I am trying to resolve this issue by going into IIS manager. IIS manager don't have list of sites and unable to add site.

Please give me solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using IIS Express while launching the program and that is why you don't see a website in IIS.

I think you want to enable directory browsing, so look here:
[How to enable Directory browsing by default on IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543761/how-to-enable-directory-browsing-by-default-on-iis-express)

Just a small side note: by careful with directory browsing on public websites as it can be a huge security risk.

Comment: I also enabled directory browsing but still facing same error.